# Would there be a point in making an SO-customized alert script?

Tags: discussion, feed, addon, scripts

I was doing some scripting / parsing of SO, then it occurred to me that I'd better check if I was doing redundant stuff.. is there existing software that supplies the following features? Has SO created these features, or have them in the pipeline?

1) I would like to have popup notification of the titles of the newest questions, and possibly their tag information as well. Liferea only tells you that "X new messages have been posted", and I can't get RSSOwl to work on my box. Would you personally find such a feature useful?

2) Post tracking. Two questions about this actually.

a) Is there any way around the red-now-orange envelope latency, aside from polling the envelope page itself? Once again, would it be a useful feature to write a script for this?

b) If you want to follow a question that was asked by someone else, my understanding is that you add it to your favorites.. as I haven't done this very much, I'd like to know how much notification you would get. Will comments left on answers to the questions show up under your 'envelope page'? Would it be useful to add the ability to track comments and edits to a particular answer only? (Not sure if that last one is possible, gotta see if answers have unchanging IDs)

Comment: Couldn't this be accomplished using the [API](http://stackapps.com)?